# Repl's Haskell sandbox skips even getLine inputs

Tags: haskell, io

I'm playing around with Haskell for the first time in Repl. Trying to simply run some IO actions with getLine and putStrLn but when I run main in GHCi it keeps skipping the second getLine. I'm using a code snippet from the [Intro to Haskell wiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Introduction_to_Haskell_IO/Actions)

The [Repl sandbox is here](https://repl.it/@isabellachen1/IncompleteImpossibleArtificialintelligence)

Not sure if this is a problem with how the code is running in Repl?

Comment: This is probably due to the Repl itself. If I use Shift+Enter instead, it works.

Comment: As pointed out, this is an issue with repl.it. I'd recommend submitting a [bug report over there](https://repl.it/bugs). For now, consider using GHC or GHCi on your own machine.